# Lightspeed Retail API call Google App Script, invalid argument error

Tags: google-apps-script, urlencode, urlfetch

I have a Google App Script that checks purchases in a [Lightspeed](https://developers.lightspeedhq.com/retail/introduction/introduction/) account, see code below. The code is working correctly, except for the last parameter in the URL (&or=voided%3Dtrue|completed%3Dtrue). When I use these exact parameters in Postman everything is working correctly, I only get sales that are voided (cancelled) or completed. In GAS, I get the following error back from the Lightspeed api:
{"httpCode":"400","httpMessage":"Bad Request","message":"findAllByFieldMatch got search for "voided=true". Did you mean: voided?","errorClass":"Exception"}

When I try different options to URL encode these parameters I get an invalid argument error from GAS. I'm thoroughly confused here, does anyone know what I'm doing wrong in GAS?

```
//Call the Lightspeed API
const accessToken = auth();
const urlRaw = `https://api.lightspeedapp.com/API/Account/${accountid}/Sale.json?load_relations=["Customer.Contact", "SalePayments.PaymentType"]&updateTime=>,${timestamp}&or=voided%3Dtrue|completed%3Dtrue`
let url = encodeURI(urlRaw);

const payload = {     
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken
    },
};

const dataRaw = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, payload);
const data = JSON.parse(dataRaw);
```

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution of your issue, in `urlRaw`, `&or=voided%3Dtrue|completed%3Dtrue` is used and `let url = encodeURI(urlRaw);` is run to `urlRaw`. I thought that this might be the reason of your issue. So when `&or=voided=true|completed=true` is used instead of `&or=voided%3Dtrue|completed%3Dtrue`, what result will you obtain?

Comment: By the way, although I looked for `&or=voided%3Dtrue|completed%3Dtrue` in the URL you provided, unfortunately, I couldn't find it. Can you provide the official document about `&or=voided%3Dtrue|completed%3Dtrue`?

Comment: I tried using decoded (&or=voided=true|completed=true) parameters like that but doesn't work either, it gives me a 500 error.

Here you can find documentation for the OR statement: https://developers.lightspeedhq.com/retail/introduction/parameters/. The voided and completed fields are on the Sale object that this api is requesting.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize my proposal was not useful for your situation. This is due to my poor skill. In order to correctly understand about your situation, can you provide the official document about `&or=voided%3Dtrue|completed%3Dtrue?`? Unfortunately, I couldn't find it from your provided URL.

Comment: No worries, I appreciate your help! I edited my previous answer with the URL to the documentation.